# Display Query results on a sub form in MS access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a Main form and a sub form. Main form has few labels and corresponding text boxes. The text boxes on main form are filled with data on clicking a command button on main form.

Secondly when any label on main form is clicked then the label name is passed to another sub which takes it as an input and runs a query and display the results on sub form (Bal_Sheet_Notes1) . However I am not able to get this second part correctly and regularly getting error messages.

The name of sub form is Bal_Sheet_Notes1

My code for second part is as below

```
Sub Bal_Sheet_Notes(Label_Name As String)
Dim ssql1 As String
ssql1 = "SELECT b.[Cat2], b.[Cat1], (sum(a.[Bal Fwd])) AS sumjan, (sum(a.[FEB])) AS sumfeb FROM Trial_Balance AS a, Act_Master AS b WHERE nz(a.[GBOBJ]) = nz(b.Object) and nz(a.[GBSUB]) = nz(b.Sub) and b.Cat6 = " & "'" & Label_Name & "'" & " GROUP BY b.[Cat2], b.[Cat1];"
Me.Forms!Bal_Sheet_Notes1.SetFocus
Me.Forms!Bal_Sheet_Notes1.RecordSource = ssql1
Me.Forms!Bal_Sheet_Notes1.Requery
End Sub
```

Please advice.

Comment: Which errors are you receiving? What do you mean regularly?

Comment: By regularly I mean when I try to fix the code with different options every time a new error comes. The last error that I am receiving is "Method or Data member not found" and the cursor goes to Me.Forms!Bal_Sheet_Notes1.setfocus line

Comment: This code is located in each label click event (Main form)

Comment: I think I did not fully clarified the forms structure. That is my mistake. Here it is. I have one main Form. On that form I have two sub forms. SubForm1 and SubForm2. All the labels are on SubForm1. The code is triggered when any label is clicked on this SubForm1. The output needs to be displayed on SubForm2. The SubForm2 is named Bal_Sheet_Notes1.

Comment: Try Me.Bal_Sheet_Notes1.setFocus

Comment: and Set Form_Bal_Sheet_Notes1.recordset = ...  You might not need the requery, as I believe setting the recordset of a form forces a requery.

Comment: Exactly what is the error message? Edit question with new info instead of comments. Code is behind the main form? @Jeffrey, does not need `Set`. These datasets have a master/child relationship? Review http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/Forms/Synchronize/LinkedSubforms.asp. The subform dataset is not editable - is that what you want?

Comment: @June7 look what I did again, I wasn't creating a recordset for the subform control, I was creating a Recordset for the form, you have to use Set or you will get a 91 runtime error.  Yes, subform datasets are not editable, but but form datasets are. i.e. Set Form_Bal_Sheet_Notes1.recordset = MyQuery will work, Me.Bal_Sheet_Notes1.recordset = MyQuery will not.

Comment: I was intending my comment to regard the RecordSource of subform, I should have included more info. So was not aware of the `Set` syntax for this. Learn something new. However, don't think intellisense popup tips will be helpful. RecordSource does not show as a property of the container control. Reference the form through the container to see form properties such as RecordSource. I always name container control different from the object it holds, such as ctrBalSht: `Me.ctrBalSht.Form.RecordSource = MyQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is not correct.
If the code is located in the SubForm1, then it should be

```
Me.Parent!SubForm2.SetFocus
Me.Parent!SubForm2.Form.RecordSource
```

If the code is located in the Main form, remove 'Parent'.
SubForm2 is the name of the subform control.
There is no need for a Requery when you set the RecordSource.

Comment: Same error is coming. Method or data member not found. This comes on first line Me.Parent!subform2.setfocus

Comment: 'Parent' is only valid if the code is actually located in Subform1?
Is that the case?
'SubForm2' needs to be the actual name of the subform control, not the subform itself. Is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky since you're calling subform2 from subform1. Your syntax should be:

```
Forms!Mainform!Subform1.Form.RecordSource = ssqul1
```

I recommend bookmarking the following page to help you differentiate between these use cases in the future: [Forms: Refer to Form and Subform properties and controls](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm)